# Uploading Images From Android/iOS To Server - ( HttpClient / WebRequest / HttpWebRequest)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

I have an older **WebForms ASP.Net web site** and I'm currently working on my first **Xamarin.Forms app**.

One of the functionalities I want **implement** is **image uploading** and this is where I get completely lost and have barely any idea of what I need to do to achieve it.

Reading countless of thread posts, both here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, the most often provided solutions include the usage of **HTTPClient**, **WebRequest** or **HttpWebRequest** - all of which I've never used.

While there are many example code snippets online of how to POST byte array of image to some PHP URL, there are close to no examples of how it could be implemented without using PHP - using ASP.NET .ASPX page instead .

Provided Microsoft example ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs(v=vs.110).aspx) always results in

```
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

(https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/942278-how-upload-file-via-c-code) Does not upload anything, but it does not show any error.

I would grately appreciate any tip, link or idea of how I could implement the said file uploading on my Xamarin app.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have to have something on the server to accept the request from the client.  If the MS example you've tried throws an error, then I would suggest you try to solve the error.  Look at the server logs to figure out what is causing the 500.